# Updating Services with promises in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I'm using angular 1.5.x on a project. I have two separate controllers with the shared `peopleService`, one of them (`dashboard-controller`) displays a list of people and another(`people-modal-controller`) lets you add people. The data gets/posts itself fine, but right now I'm having trouble having the original list update whenever a new person is added. Sidenote: I'm not sure if this is important or not but right now I'm trying to follow best practice as use Controller As syntax instead of $scope. Here is my code.

people-service.js

```
logbook.service('peopleService', function($http){
var people;

function getPeople(){
    if ( angular.isDefined( people ) ) return $q.when( people );
    return $http.get('/api/v1/people').then(function(data) {
        people = data;
        return people;
    }
)};

return {
    getPeople: getPeople(),
}    
})
```

dashboard-controller.js

```
logbook.controller('dashboardController', function($http, $scope, $httpParamSerializerJQLike, peopleService){
    var self = this;
    peopleService.getPeople.then(function(response){
    self.people = response.data;
}
```

people-modal-controller.js

```
logbook.controller('peopleModalController', function($http, $scope, $httpParamSerializerJQLike, ngDialog, peopleService){
var self = this;

self.savePerson = function(person){
        $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/api/people',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
            'name': person.name,
        }),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        self.name = null;
        peopleService.getPeople;            
    }).catch(function(response){
        self.formError = response.data.error.message;
    })
```

index.html

`<li ng-repeat="person in dashboard.people.data">{{ person.name }}</li>`

Comment: in a service, it should be `getPeople: getPeople` instead of calling method on getPeople `getPeople: getPeople(),`

Comment: I get `TypeError: peopleService.getPeople.then is not a function` in the console when I do this, how should I change my controllers to reflect this?

Comment: then inside controller, you should do function call like `peopleService.getPeople().then`

Comment: Code runs again (thanks!) but unfortunately the list of people is still not updating after a new Person is added.

Comment: Could you add your whole template please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use [ngResource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) or similar module for this. `savePerson` function should be a part of the same `peopleService`. And in this case you can get the benefit of sharing scope between controllers. You can do something like

```
logbook.controller('dashboardController', function($rootScope, peopleService){
   $rootScope.people = [];
  peopleService.query().$promise.then(function(people) {
    $rootScope.people = people;
  });
}
```

Then

```
logbook.controller('peopleModalController', function($rootScope, peopleService){
self = this;
self.savePerson = function(person){
   var newPerson = new peopleService(person);
   newPerson.$save().$promise.then(function(person) {
    $rootScope.people.push(person);
  });
}
```

But the best way is to use `peopleService.query().$promise` in your router in `resolve` parameter

```
resolve: {
  people(peopleService) {
    return peopleService.query().$promise;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, totally worked for me. :P I figured $rootScope was kind of a hacky way to do it but I guess it's there to be used, eh?

Comment: Although it solves your problem if you don't use people anywhere else it's not a good practice to assign variables to the `$rootScope`. Much better to design your app in a way that `peopleModalController` would be inside `dashboardController` and would inherit it's `$scope`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your service must be something like this:

```
logbook.service('peopleService', function($http){
    var people;

    function getPeople() {
        return angular.isDefined(people) ? $q.when(people) : refreshPeople();
    };

    function refreshPeople() {
        return $http.get('/api/v1/people')
            .then(function(data) {
                people = data;
                return people;
            })
    };

    return {
        getPeople: getPeople,
        refreshPeople: refreshPeople
    };
})
```